# Material UI drawer how to change main based on router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I am using material-ui's drawer and I want to change main based on react router. Any idea how I can do that ? I tried like in the code below but it doesn't work. I already tried to use also the  before the code but it gives me an error saying that I tried to hack too much and to find another way.

Thanks!

```
import { NavLink, Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';
import StatutulUAT from '../components/StatutulUAT';

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  appBar: {
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
  },
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth,
    flexShrink: 0,
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
  },
  toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
}));

export default function ClippedDrawer() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [uat, setUat] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
            Certeju De Sus
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <Drawer
        className={classes.drawer}
        variant="permanent"
        classes={{
          paper: classes.drawerPaper,
        }}
      >
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <List>
          {['Something', 'Something'].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem button key={text} component={NavLink} to="/uat">
              <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
              <ListItemText primary={text} />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List
      </Drawer>
     {
       <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/uat">
           <StatutulUAT/>
         </Route>
       </Switch>
       }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: did you figure this out?